# Cache Performance with Global Variables

Tags: c, caching

I have a non code specific question about C. I was wondering how global variables fare when it comes to cache misses as opposed to having the variables on the heap via malloc?

Note: I know heap allocation incurs its own speed costs but ignore that for this question. Imagine I have to make one call to malloc anyway and decide to use the first k bytes to store what I would otherwise keep as a global array. Would it be more cache friendly to keep it as a global or keep it on the heap segment I am actively using in my program.

Comment: Heap allocation only incurs a (often minor) performance hit when actually allocating and freeing the memory. Once the memory has been allocated and mapped to a process then it's no different from any of the other memory used by the process (for global data in one way or another, or for local data on the stack).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Right but if you're manipulating a lot of memory that you got via a call to malloc, and also jumping to the global data section, would that mess with locality?

Comment: It might, or it might not. It depends on many factors. If you're on a system which supports [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) you can use its cache-tools to profile cache problems. Or you can just try an measure your algorithm times yourself. But first of all you should not try and worry about micromanaging these things until they actually become a problem, premature optimizations and all that. Concentrate on writing good, readable and maintainable code first of all, and do optimizations only when and *where* needed.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Haha agreed but right now I'm specifically messing with optimizations :p 

Unfortunately i haven't been able to master callgrind yet. If you have any good resources for it I would love a reference but other than that, I'll keep grinding.